# Traces over ground plane

Tags: pcb, routing, via, ground-plane, trace

Sometimes it cannot be avoided to run traces over a ground plane (bottom layer) in a two layer PCB.

I have two questions regarding this:

1. In the (simplified) example below, what is preferred? To use two small vias, minimizing the interruption of the ground plane (R1 to R3), preventing ground loops, but having more vias, or using a large line via the ground plane (r2 to R4)?
2. In most cases I can chose to have either a VCC line (5 or 3.3V) or a signal line (MIDI, DMX, 31-250 kbps) run over the ground plane when needed. Is there any preference?

[image]

Comment: I put ground plane on both layers, basically everywhere there is not a signal, and use vias to connect the two layers.

Comment: You can find lot of info regarding ground planes on the web (e.g. https://aerospacepal.com/pcb-plane-cuts-kill-emc/) and porbably on this site as wel

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a good idea, although high likely it will not prevent the need of via's for VCC and/or signal traces. Or do you have scattered ground areas on both sides?

Comment: Some other hits on "board layout guidelines": [Learn EMC](https://learnemc.com/pcb-layout), [Infineon appnote 24026](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-AP2402635_General_PCB-AN-v03_05-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d46261ff5777016229f8523036f1), [Analog design handbook](https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/design-handbooks/Basic-Linear-Design/Chapter12.pdf)

Comment: (Although I marked my answer as duplicate, the second part is not really answered (and high likely not important).

Comment: @Huisman Thanks for all that info ... I hope I can work my way through that (I don't have an electronical background).

Comment: The first 2 of 4 links I posted are easy to read..

Comment: Scattered ground areas on both sides. Keep signal vias to a minimum, use the vias to connect all the Gnd areas together.  Sometimes you can shift signal paths around  a little to let Gnd patches connect up on the same layer as well.

Comment: I will read them (in the next days I have hopefully some time). I really appreciate the links and all info.

Comment: Thanks, although I still see some need for VCC or signal vias, but I will try a new design of my current PCB design with different GND areas and see how it will look like.

Comment: @CrossRoads  In the original question, R1-R3 is a better layout, even though it has got more vias.

Comment: Not if those are high frequency or critical signals @ Nick Alexeev. More vias introduce more chances for signal corruption. VCC and Gnd planes aren't critical in that respect.

Comment: @CrossRoads Thanks for that ... together with Andy Aka's answer, I will prevent as much as possible signal traces going through via's, I will check if I can make some better ground plane layout, and if I need vias for non ground traces, I will use VCC traces through vias instead of signal traces. Btw, this design is very low frequency, but in the future I probably will use SPI signals which might get upto 1 or 2 MHz.

Comment: I do SPI at 8 MHz with Arduino chips (328P, 1284P, 2560) and use minimal vias in traces and see good results. I think you will too.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know, I might use faster CPUs (STM32F1/F4) eventually, but I doubt I need more than a few MHz of SPI or other protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Generalizing, the best option is to minimize disruption to the ground plane** and this means using the interconnection method between R1 and R3 as shown in your diagram.
2. **Generalizing, the best option is to minimize disruption to the ground plane** but, now that I understand what you are asking, I'd put power tracks onto the ground layer in preference to signals. Reason: Power tracks are usually DC or low frequency (and highly capacitively coupled to real GP) and can act reasonably well as a surrogate ground plane to signal tracks on the other layer.

Comment: The first is clear, but if I have to chose between a via routing a VCC or signal trace over the ground layer, which should I chose out of these two types?

Comment: (Although I marked my answer as duplicate, the second part is not really answered (and high likely not important).

Comment: @MichelKeijzers Aha I see what you mean - my preference is to route power temporarily onto the ground plane rather than signals because, power tracks "look" like ground plane to signals and behave like ground planes.

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer (including a reason).